Four-divergence term in Lagrangian
It is known that adding a four-divergence term, $\partial_\mu A^\mu$ does not affect the equations of motion. I am trying to reason this based on the Euler-Lagrange equation. But I want to show this explicitly by adding the term to the Lagrangian (density), and taking the derivatives of this term should give zero.
But $\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}(\partial_\alpha A^\alpha) =\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}(\delta^\mu_ \alpha \partial_\mu \eta^{\alpha \nu}A_\nu) = \eta^{\mu \nu}$
Doesn't this add an extra term technically to the equations of motion? $\eta$ is here the metric tensor.
Also, $\frac{\partial}{\partial A_\nu}(\partial ^\alpha A_\alpha) = \frac{\partial}{\partial A_\nu}(\partial^\alpha \delta^\nu_\alpha A_\nu)=\partial^\nu$, which also seems to add an extra term.
The reason why I am doing that because in terms of the steps, it is analogous to calculating: $\frac{\partial}{\partial A_\nu}(J^\alpha A_\alpha) = J^\nu$. I am applying the same logic now to $\frac{\partial}{\partial A_\nu}(\partial^\alpha A_\alpha)$ and I indeed get a contradicting result.
These terms are not regular terms since they are the metric tensor and derivative operator, but still, if I add a four divergence and explicitly calculate the derivatives, I get extra terms. How do I justify this that it still doesn't change the equation of motion?
I am assuming a constant metric tensor.

Be careful with indices; none should appear thrice. The correct calculation is$$\partial_\mu\frac{\partial_\rho A^\rho}{\partial\partial_\mu A_\nu}=\partial_\mu(\delta_\rho^\mu\eta^{\nu\rho})=\cdots$$(I leave you to simplify).

I indeed messed up the indices. With your indices, Would that give zero somehow? If so how?

I'm starting to think you're not assuming a constant metric tensor, in which case you need to exploit $\sqrt{|\eta|}\nabla_\rho A^\rho=\partial_\rho(\sqrt{|\eta|}A^\rho)$ to prove the general result in curved spacetimes.

I am assuming a constant metric tensor.

Hi Stallmp. Hint: Before attempting to prove it in field theory, do you understand the proof in point mechanics?

Yes I do. I understand conceptually that you are like adding a constant to the Lagrangian, but I just want to see it explicitly that it vanishes when taking the derivative

Edit: the indices are now fixed.


It is known that adding a four divergence term, $\partial_\mu A^\mu$ does not affect the equations of motion. I am trying to reason this based on the Euler-Lagrange equation. But I want to show this explicitly by adding the term to the Lagrangian (density), and taking the derivatives of this term should give zero.


But $\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}(\partial_\alpha A^\alpha) =\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}(\delta^\mu_ \alpha \partial_\mu \eta^{\alpha \nu}A_\nu) = \eta^{\mu \nu}$

Yes, but $\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}(\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)$ would not appear in the equations of motion by itself, it would appear as part of the term:
$$
\partial_\mu \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}\;,
$$
but
$$
\partial_\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}(\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)
=\partial_\mu\eta^{\mu\nu} = 0\;,
$$
so there is no contribution to the equations of motion.


Also, $\frac{\partial}{\partial A_\nu}(\partial ^\alpha A_\alpha) = \partial ^\nu$, which also seems to add an extra term.

No, the above-quoted equation is just wrong. You have to treat $A_\nu$ and $\partial_\mu A_\nu$ independently to consistently arrive at the equations of motion:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A_\nu} - \partial_\mu \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)} = 0\;.
$$
When $L=\partial \cdot A$ the first term above is zero since there is no dependence on $A_\nu$, only $\partial_\mu A_\nu$. The second term above is also zero since, as explained above, $\partial_\mu \eta^{\mu\nu}=0$.


Regarding why you must treat $A$ and $\partial_\mu A$ independently, you must do so because otherwise our previously-agreed understanding of the Largrangian and the action makes no sense. (Of course, $A$ and $\partial_\mu A$ are not literally independent, but you just have to treat them as such in the expression for the Lagrangian function. See below for why.)
I'll provide a 1d example below (so no $\mu$ index) and I'll thus consider only $A(t)$ and $\dot A(t)$.
For example, suppose we have a Lagrangian that is a function of two independent variables
$$
L(a, b) = a^4 + b^2
$$
and suppose that we have an action given by
$$
S = \int dt L(A(t), \dot A(t)) = \int dt \left(A^4+\dot A^2\right)\;,
$$
where we have all now agreed that we are evaluating the function $L$ at $a=A(t)$ and at $b=\dot A(t)$, but this does not mean anything other than that. In particular, even thought $A$ and $\dot A$ are clearly related, that does not change how we specified our function in terms of $a$ and $b$.
Now, if we let $A\to A+\delta A$ (and thus so too $\dot A \to \dot A + \delta \dot A$) we have
$$
\delta S = \int dt \left( 
\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}\right|_{a=A(t),b=\dot A(t)}\delta A(t)
+
\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial b}\right|_{a=A(t),b=\dot A(t)}\delta \dot A(t)
\right)
$$
$$
=\int dt \left( 
4A(t)^3\delta A(t)
+
2\dot A(t)\delta \dot A(t)
\right)\;,
$$
where I'm still treating the $a$ and $b$ variables as independent because I have to or else I don't get the right expression for the change in the action. And just because I evaluated $a=A(t)$ and $b=\dot A(t)$ does not change this fact--I need to consider how $L$ changes with $a$ and with $b$ because changing $A\to A+\delta A$ also changes $\dot A \to \dot A + \delta \dot A$ (not in some arbitrary way, where I can mix up $A$ and $\dot A$ however I like, but rather precisely as specified above).
Now, if I want to end up with the usual expression for a functional derivative, I can also integrate by parts on the second term and drop the surface term and end up with:
$$
\delta S = \int dt \delta A(t)\left( 
\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}\right|_{a=A(t),b=\dot A(t)}
-
\frac{d}{dt}\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial b}\right|_{a=A(t),b=\dot A(t)}
\right)
$$
and thus the Lagrange EOM:
$$
\left( 
\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}\right|_{a=A(t),b=\dot A(t)}
-
\frac{d}{dt}\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial b}\right|_{a=A(t),b=\dot A(t)}
\right)=0\;.
$$
I hope that by writing each independent variable of the Lagrangian as an $a$ or a $b$ helps you see what is happening here...

Thanks for your comment! I understand that you have to treat $A_\nu$ and $\partial_\mu A_\nu$ separately. But that is the thing that confuses me, because I am not doing anything illegal in order to arrive at the result that $\frac{\partial}{\partial A_\nu}(\partial ^\alpha A_\alpha) = \partial ^\nu$ right? I will edit the post to add additional steps, so please take a look again at the post.

What you are writing about $\partial^\nu$ does not make any sense to me. You can't just effectively cancel the $A$s and end up with a bare $\partial^\nu$. It doesn't make sense in the context of generating the Lagrange EOMs, and you have not provided a sufficient explanation to provide any other reasonable sense to the equation.

@Stallmp You should be getting: $${\partial\over\partial A_\nu}(\partial^\alpha A_\alpha)=0,$$ since $A_\nu$ and $\partial_\mu A_\nu$ are independent.

I've added a little more about why we treat $A$ and $\dot A$ as independent when generating the Lagrange EOMs even those it seems perhaps counterintuitive...

The reason why I am doing that because in terms of the steps, it is analogous to calculating: $\frac{\partial}{\partial A_\nu}(J^\alpha A_\alpha) = J^\nu$. I am applying the same logic now to $\frac{\partial}{\partial A_\nu}(\partial^\alpha A_\alpha)$ and I indeed get a contradicting result. My question is there a concrete reason wrong with the procedure, since I am doing the same steps. I indeed understand that they should conceptually be treated independently. Thanks a lot for the addition!

@Stallmp Yes, there is a concrete reason why what you are doing is wrong. I added some text to the bottom of my post to explain, but perhaps it is just too much for a single post on a website like this. This should be explained in most classical mechanics books, e.g., Goldstein. Or in mathematical physics books in the section on calculus of variations

Thanks a lot for your clear explanation! It's definitely helpful to understand better why they should be treated separately.
